# Is it possible to run a task periodically in Background - iOS 4

Tags: iphone, ios4, gps, core-location

I want to poll the location from GPS in the background. So we used a NSTimer and performed periodic checks in the timer tick. In other words, can we schedule NSTimer while the app is in Background?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't periodically execute arbitrary code, but you can get pinged on significant location changes via [startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-CH3-SW43) in CLLocationManager.